# Open new window when the previous is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, window.open

Is there a way to open a new window when the previous is closed?

I have a website and user clicks a button, I show him a popup. And when he leaves the popup ( clicking on close button ) I want to open another window.

Comment: yes there is. show us what you have tried (if you think a bit the answer is in the question itself) and show us where you get stuck at :)

Comment: So basically your expected behaviour is to open new popup again and again? Modern browsers don't like that, just like many users... This is no more possible in javascript only

Comment: Yes my expected behaviour is basically open a new popup each time the previous one is closed. In fact, I need only two popups. You say it's not possible with javascript only but can it be done other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the onclick function on your close button to open a new window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).on('click', '.close', function(){

   //open new window here
  });

});
```

Comment: But what if the user close the window with the native button ? :)

Comment: As per your question...when someone close that popup, new window will be opened, right? It was not about the window close button.

Comment: I think OP is talking about close button of new window, which btw can be closed without any click. I think OP wants something like "You win a iphone","Amazing girls want fun near your area", "your penis bigger in a week", etc...

Comment: Taniya, thanks for your answer, however it is only working if I close the window with a button on my page. I wanted to have this effect when the user clicks the close button in the window.

Comment: In that case you can use $(window).close(function(){ window.open('url', 'window name');  return false; });